# Get address from location coordinates and add it to a textview

Tags: android

This my code to get the current location I wanted to add the address of the current location in text View. How can we add the address and show current location simultaneously. I am not able to get how to add text view in which address of the current location is shown.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

        }
    }
    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //vars
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        getLocationPermission();
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your should take a look to [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address) class in the Android framework location APIs.

Basically you have to follow three steps:

1. Create the Geocoder

```kotlin
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
    // ...
}
```

2. Define the constants to contain the values you want to retrieve:

```kotlin
object Constants {
    const val SUCCESS_RESULT = 0
    const val FAILURE_RESULT = 1
    const val PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationaddress"
    const val RECEIVER = "$PACKAGE_NAME.RECEIVER"
    const val RESULT_DATA_KEY = "${PACKAGE_NAME}.RESULT_DATA_KEY"
    const val LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA = "${PACKAGE_NAME}.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA"
}
```

3. Retrieve a list of addresses from your latitude/longitude coordinates

```kotlin
// Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
    val location = intent.getParcelableExtra(
            Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA)

    // ...

    var addresses: List<Address> = emptyList()

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                location.latitude,
                location.longitude,
                // In this sample, we get just a single address.
                1)
    } catch (ioException: IOException) {
        // Catch network or other I/O problems.
        errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available)
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException)
    } catch (illegalArgumentException: IllegalArgumentException) {
        // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
        errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used)
        Log.e(TAG, "$errorMessage. Latitude = $location.latitude , " +
                "Longitude =  $location.longitude", illegalArgumentException)
    }
```